# Combine url with multiple same args from submitted form

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, checkbox

I have a form with multiple checkboxes, all called filter. When the form gets submitted, they get added to the URL, "example.com/?filter=var", as expected.

When there are multiple checkboxes selected, they get added to the url like so: "example.com/?filter=var&filter=var2".

Is it possible to change this somehow? I need them in the url as "example.com/?filter=var+var2".

Is this possible to achieve somehow? Using Javascript is no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a function call to your Submit button and leave your form tag like this `<form>`.

```
$(function () {
  $('#target').click(function () {
    var checkValues = $('input[name=checkboxlist]:checked').map(function() {
        return $(this).parent().text();
    }).get().join('+');
    window.location.href = "http://example.com/?filter="+checkValues;
  });
});​
```

Comment: I actually just tried this again and it adds them to the url like so:
"example.com/?filter=var,var2", with commas instead of +'s.

Comment: Actually, adding `.join('+')` after `get().` worked ;)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `hidden` field for that, and in the submit event you set it's value with the filters. The hidden will get the name as `filter` and the checkboxes' values will be ignored:

```js
//$("form").on("submit", function() {
$('input[type="submit"]').on("click", function() {
 var filter = [];
 $('input[type="checkbox"]:checked').each(function() {
   filter.push(this.value);
  });
  
  $("#filter").val(filter.join("+"));
  console.log("filters", filter.join("+"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="hidden" name="filter" id="filter" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="val1" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="val2" />
  <input type="checkbox" value="val3" />
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

Use `$("form").on("submit", function() {` instead of the event in the button. I just commented it because you can't submit in StackOverflow snippet.

[Fiddle Version](https://jsfiddle.net/9r6rso3r/)